# Problem with Author page redirect

Tags: plugins, rewrite-rules

When trying to access the author's page (i.e. example.com/author/john) I am redirected to Woocommerce's shop page, however, if john is an admin, then I am redirected to author.php page correctly... any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yoast Plugin, you must go to Dashboard > General > Open The Configuration wizar > the choose "Multi User" in of the step in it

Trust me It works

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no straight forward answer,since, it is unclear what template is used. But as long as you want ideas, these steps may help you to understand why.

1. check template file hierarchy to understand it better:
   documentation link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Which_Template_File_is_Used.3F
2. make sure that "john" really uses author.php (it may use archive.php or index.php)
3. check what view your Woo Commerce shop uses.

---

My guess is that other users don't have any posts so you get index.php view (which is overwritten by Woo Commerce)